# Loopt into an Array to find id using React js with hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a page with a list of product cards. When I click on one of the product cards, I want to be redirected to the product detail page of the selected product. So what I want now is to switch class components with functional components.

### `products.json`

```
{
  "shoes": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sneakerși piele Massimo Dutti",
        "price": 135,
        "currency": "LEI",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Rz8lVQa.jpg",
        "size": 45,
        "colour": "Negru",
        "material": "Piele",
        "brand": "Massimo Dutti",
        "description": "Sneakerși din piele cu talpă inițial albă, din colecția de toamnă-iarnă 2019, Massimo Dutti."
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Teniși negri Polo Ralph Lauren",
        "price": 100,
        "currency": "LEI",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Og3Oh24.jpg",
        "size": 45,
        "colour": "Negru",
        "material": "Pânză",
        "brand": "Polo Ralph Lauren",
        "description": "Teniși din pânză cu talpă inițial albă, din colecția de primăvară-vară 2019, Fashion Days."
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Ghete din piele maro Massimo",
        "price": 185,
        "currency": "LEI",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/zoqSu87.jpg",
        "size": 45,
        "colour": "Maro",
        "material": "Piele",
        "brand": "Massimo Dutti",
        "description": "Ghete maro din piele, din colecția de toamnă-iarnă 2017, Massimo Dutti."
      }
    ],
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/X0qldXO.jpg",
    "name": "Încălțăminte",
    "description": "Ghete, pantofi, sneakerși: finețe garantată!"
  },
  "sweaters": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Pulovăr finuț cu guler",
        "price": 95,
        "currency": "LEI",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/6afzuEr.jpg",
        "size": "L",
        "colour": "Maro",
        "material": "Cașmir",
        "brand": "DS Damat",
        "description": "Pulovăr din cașmir, slim fit, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2019, DS Damat."
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Pulovăr multicolor",
        "price": 105,
        "currency": "LEI",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/s0VytKc.jpg",
        "size": "L",
        "colour": "Multicolor",
        "material": "Bumbac",
        "brand": "McNeal",
        "description": "Pulovăr multicolor, colecția toamnă-iarnă 209, McNeal."
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Pulovăr călduros și frumos",
        "price": 165,
        "currency": "LEI",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/BWGgzlK.jpg",
        "size": "L",
        "colour": "Multicolor",
        "material": "Lână",
        "brand": "SELECTED",
        "description": "Pulovăr din lână, în carouri, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2019, SELECTED."
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Pulovăr din lână",
        "price": 160,
        "currency": "LEI",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/dTcMbHT.jpg",
        "size": "L",
        "colour": "Crem",
        "material": "Lână",
        "brand": "Massimo Dutti",
        "description": "Pulovăr din lână cu model, colecția toamnă-iarnă 2019, Massimo Dutti."
      }
    ],
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/SZU7liE.jpg",
    "name": "Pulovere",
    "description": "Pulovărașe elegănțele, slim, clasă superioară."
  }
}
```

I have tried to refactor the code using hooks, but somehow if I don't use component lifecycle and loop trough `categoryValues`, the value of `category.items` is `undefined`.

### `Product.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import products from "../utils/products.json";

class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      product: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    const productId = match.params.productId;
    const categoryValues = Object.values(products);
    console.log(categoryValues);

    let currentProduct;

    categoryValues.forEach((category) => {
      const findResult = category.items.find((product) => {
        console.log(typeof productId, typeof product.id);
        return product.id === Number(productId);
      });
      if (findResult) {
        currentProduct = findResult;
      }
    });

    this.setState({ product: currentProduct });
  }

  render() {
    const { product } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="product-page content-min-height container-fluid container-min-max-width">
        <h1 className="my-5 h2">{product.name}</h1>
        <div className="product-info d-flex">
          <div className="image-wrapper d-flex mr-5">
            <img src={product.image} alt="Product presentation" />
          </div>
          <div className="product-details">
            <p className="h3 text-danger">
              {product.price} {product.currency}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: Your question is very broad and requires reading a bunch of code to understand what you're trying to do. If you edit the question and provide better context, explain why you're looping through the array and how you're using the id to find a specific element while pointing out smaller snippets of code, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have added details about the code functionality.

Comment: I’ve edited you answer for better clarity, but it sounds like the issue comes from the process of converting a class component to a functional component. If you add the refactored code with the functional component I think it'll be possible to help you fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state initializer of the `useState` hook for this. It will only be executed the first time.

```
const findProduct = (id) => { ... };
const ProductPage = (props) => {
  const [product] = useState(() => findProduct(props.match.params.productId));
  return <ProductDetails product={product} />;
};
```